# In an ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API project, how can I change the name of the authentication ticket?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication

In an ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API project, I am trying to change the name of the authentication ticket created by:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignInAsync
```

to be different depending on the web site from which a user is logging into the API.

(*I cannot upgrade to a later version of ASP.NET Core at this time*).

I have created this class to set a different authorization cookie name depending on the client:

```
public class CustomCookieMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CustomCookieMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var defaultCookieName = ".AspNetCore.Cookies";
        var port = context.Request.Host.Port;
        var path = context.Request.PathBase;

        var cookieName = $"{defaultCookieName}_{port}_{path}";

        context.Response.OnStarting(state =>
                {
                    var httpContext = (HttpContext)state;
                    var cookieOptions = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>>();
                    cookieOptions.Value.Cookie.Name = cookieName;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }, context);

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

And in the `Configure` method of my `Startup` class, I am adding the middleware class like this:

```
app.UseMiddleware<CustomCookieMiddleware>();
```

Additionally, I have created this custom cookie manager class:

```
public class CustomCookieManager : ICookieManager
{
    public string CookieName { get; private set; }

    private readonly ICookieManager _originalCookieManager;

    public CustomCookieManager(ICookieManager originalCookieManager)
    {
        _originalCookieManager = originalCookieManager;
    }

    public void AppendResponseCookie(HttpContext context, string key, string value, CookieOptions options)
    {
        var defaultCookieName = ".AspNetCore.Cookies";
        var port = context.Request.Host.Port;
        var path = context.Request.PathBase;

        key = $"{defaultCookieName}_{port}_{path}";

        CookieName = key;

        _originalCookieManager.AppendResponseCookie(context, key, value, options);
    }

    public void DeleteCookie(HttpContext context, string key, CookieOptions options)
    {
        _originalCookieManager.DeleteCookie(context, key, options);
    }

    public string GetRequestCookie(HttpContext context, string key)
    {
        return _originalCookieManager.GetRequestCookie(context, key);
    }   
}
```

In the `ServiceConfiguration` method of my `Startup` class, I am setting an instance of this class as the `CookieManager`, like this:

```
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.CookieManager = new CustomCookieManager(new ChunkingCookieManager());
        });
```

The name of the authentication ticket is indeed changed like I want it to be, depending on the web site from which the user is logging in.

However, after a user logs in, `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` always returns false.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Authentication is failing because  middleware  might not recognize cookie correctly. to resolve this you have to make sure the you are getting correct cookie name in the coming request and configure the `CookieAuthenticationOptions` to use that name. you can achieve this by adding middleware before the authentication middleware that sets the cookie name and then make sure the `CookieAuthenticationOptions` uses this name when authenticating the request.

Below is the code you could try:

```
public class CustomCookieMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IOptionsMonitor<CookieAuthenticationOptions> _optionsMonitor;
    
    public CustomCookieMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IOptionsMonitor<CookieAuthenticationOptions> optionsMonitor)
    {
        _next = next;
        _optionsMonitor = optionsMonitor;
    }
    
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var defaultCookieName = ".AspNetCore.Cookies";
        var port = context.Request.Host.Port?.ToString();
        var path = context.Request.Path;

        var cookieName = $"{defaultCookieName}_{port}_{path}";
        
        var options = _optionsMonitor.Get(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        options.Cookie.Name = cookieName;

        context.Items[CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme] = options;

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

After that in your `Configure` method make sure `CustomCookieMiddleware` is invoked before any authentication-related middleware.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // ...

    app.UseMiddleware<CustomCookieMiddleware>();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    
    // ...
}
```

Startup.ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        // your default configurations
    });
```